# useFetch on Nuxt.js can't get response headers

Tags: nuxt.js

Now I'm trying to implement a util function to get CSRF token via API(Server side is Laravel with Sanctum).
I use `useFetch` but I can't get response header values.

I checked logs on the client side and server side.
On the client side, headers was empty, but on the server side it had a value. Nevertheless, when I try to access headers, I get `undefined`.

How can I get headers value?

■My Code

```js
export default async () => {
    const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
    const response = await useFetch(`${runtimeConfig.public.apiUrl}/sanctum/csrf-cookie`, {
        onResponse({ request, response, options }) {
            console.log(`server side is ${process.server}`);
            console.log(response.headers);
        },
    });
    return response;
}
```

■Log on Client

```
server side is false
Headers {}
```

■Log on Server

```
server side is true
HeadersList {
  cookies: [
    'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkpGRXk2SFF0d1FIdWN1b2FTUDFkbmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU1p3QzZXM2Z1NDdSMGhLaWJFa1BUOFhRZjdBWTY4QWdFdUp0N0FCWGJCTTB0OXhYVWM2bHZTeUtNSU5BZzdkYlNJZSsvVTlDM2lIQVFCektLWUhxR2tEbU1mb3pYRXJrNWhucFhNSTc4NHYzUnorempLcG5UQjhrT05WQlBuY1MiLCJtYWMiOiI2ZDZiOTJiMGEzZDRiZjczOWYzY2U1MWVkMjQyZDk3MDE3ZWU1ZWYwZjg2ZWRmZDg5YWFjZTk3ZTRjNDlkZjI0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax',
    'laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikx4dzgvTjBqUEoxUktSLzh0S3VPMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUEFmM3BFTEtZMXUyRGVrdlljMmxFSGh2RENnejh4UzlpRXFCMDc5bWhQdHZXcCtoVVl2a1hTTGJqUnhCMFUrbnpqaEtiMFRnRE9MUFlLQTdmTkhQNmdxMWZMSlB5L3h0KzdmWUVOaERjbGxZVUJVZWFua09TSUo0dGpVZDJ5TjYiLCJtYWMiOiJiNjAxMTM2NmRkZTFmNDY4YjRmM2MyMzhkNTQ0NDJjNTU1ZDkzMmFkMmUyNmUyNjg4NjlhMjBkYjEzM2Y4NTc3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax',
    'ne67qM6BrMnsBHmfYiUenlmWEj7UcMOUguqpqK50=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; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax'
  ],
  [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(8) {
    'access-control-allow-credentials' => { name: 'access-control-allow-credentials', value: 'true' },
    'access-control-allow-origin' => {
      name: 'access-control-allow-origin',
      value: 'http://localhost:3000'
    },
    'cache-control' => { name: 'cache-control', value: 'no-cache, private' },
    'connection' => { name: 'connection', value: 'close' },
    'date' => { name: 'date', value: 'Thu, 08 Feb 2024 09:24:58 GMT' },
    'host' => { name: 'host', value: 'localhost:8000' },
    'set-cookie' => {
      name: 'set-cookie',
      value: 'XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkpGRXk2SFF0d1FIdWN1b2FTUDFkbmc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiU1p3QzZXM2Z1NDdSMGhLaWJFa1BUOFhRZjdBWTY4QWdFdUp0N0FCWGJCTTB0OXhYVWM2bHZTeUtNSU5BZzdkYlNJZSsvVTlDM2lIQVFCektLWUhxR2tEbU1mb3pYRXJrNWhucFhNSTc4NHYzUnorempLcG5UQjhrT05WQlBuY1MiLCJtYWMiOiI2ZDZiOTJiMGEzZDRiZjczOWYzY2U1MWVkMjQyZDk3MDE3ZWU1ZWYwZjg2ZWRmZDg5YWFjZTk3ZTRjNDlkZjI0IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; samesite=lax, laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikx4dzgvTjBqUEoxUktSLzh0S3VPMnc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiUEFmM3BFTEtZMXUyRGVrdlljMmxFSGh2RENnejh4UzlpRXFCMDc5bWhQdHZXcCtoVVl2a1hTTGJqUnhCMFUrbnpqaEtiMFRnRE9MUFlLQTdmTkhQNmdxMWZMSlB5L3h0KzdmWUVOaERjbGxZVUJVZWFua09TSUo0dGpVZDJ5TjYiLCJtYWMiOiJiNjAxMTM2NmRkZTFmNDY4YjRmM2MyMzhkNTQ0NDJjNTU1ZDkzMmFkMmUyNmUyNjg4NjlhMjBkYjEzM2Y4NTc3IiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax, ne67qM6BrMnsBHmfYiUenlmWEj7UcMOUguqpqK50=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; expires=Thu, 08 Feb 2024 11:24:58 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax'
    },
    'x-powered-by' => { name: 'x-powered-by', value: 'PHP/8.3.1' }
  },
  [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
```

Answer (score 0):

It can access to header value via `response.headers.get('header name')`